# Flutter - function not executing and view not displayed

Tags: function, flutter, view

In a view, when the user tap on a button, I am doing this

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>ViewPDFSelectedFirebase(result)));
```

this is supposed to transfert to the view bellow a url named 'result'
Then, this url, is supposed to be managed by loadFirebase(String url), then
_storeFile(String url, List bytes) should be executed and finally call

void openPDF(BuildContext context, File file) => Navigator.of(context).push(
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PDFViewerPage( file: file,)),);

The last one is supposed to display a scaffold with the content of a file.

It seems that the LoadFirebase and _StoreFile are not working. I guess it is because they are not at the right place. But I do not understand where I should use them. I might have other errors.
If you could advise, it would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'new_view_pdf_storage.dart';

class ViewPDFSelectedFirebase extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  const ViewPDFSelectedFirebase({Key key,this.url, }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewPDFSelectedFirebaseState createState() => _ViewPDFSelectedFirebaseState();
}

 class _ViewPDFSelectedFirebaseState extends State<ViewPDFSelectedFirebase> {
   test() async{
   final  urlSelected = url;
   print('urlSelected='+ urlSelected.toString());
   final file = await loadFirebase(urlSelected.toString());
   if (file==null) return;
   openPDF(this.context, file);

   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(child: Text (basename(url.toString())))),
//it displays on the screen 'Instance of context' => I don't know why. I was expecting to see a url instead.
    );
  }
  static Future<File> loadFirebase(String url) async {
    try {
      final refPDF = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(url);
      final bytes = await refPDF.getData();
      return _storeFile(url, bytes);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<File> _storeFile(String url, List<int> bytes) async {
    final filename = basename(url);
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    return file;
  }

   void openPDF(BuildContext context, File file) => Navigator.of(context).push(
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PDFViewerPage( file: file,)),);
}

class PDFViewerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final File file;

  const PDFViewerPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.file,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PDFViewerPageState createState() => _PDFViewerPageState();
}

class _PDFViewerPageState extends State<PDFViewerPage> {
  PDFViewController controller;
  int pages = 0;
  int indexPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final name = basename(widget.file.path);
    final text = '${indexPage + 1} of $pages';

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(name),
        actions: pages >= 2
        ? [
        Center(child: Text(text)),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left, size: 32),
          onPressed: () {
            final page = indexPage == 0 ? pages : indexPage - 1;
            controller.setPage(page);
          },
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right, size: 32),
          onPressed: () {
            final page = indexPage == pages - 1 ? 0 : indexPage + 1;
            controller.setPage(page);
          },
        ),
        ]
        : null,
      ),
      body: PDFView(
        filePath: widget.file.path,
        // autoSpacing: false,
        // swipeHorizontal: true,
        // pageSnap: false,
        // pageFling: false,
        onRender: (pages) => setState(() => this.pages = pages),
        onViewCreated: (controller) =>
            setState(() => this.controller = controller),
        onPageChanged: (indexPage, _) =>
            setState(() => this.indexPage = indexPage),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have modified the code and split it. But even though, I do not find how to solve this.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'new_class_scafold.dart';

class ViewPDFSelectedFirebase extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  const ViewPDFSelectedFirebase(this.url,{Key key, }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewPDFSelectedFirebaseState createState() => _ViewPDFSelectedFirebaseState();
}

 class _ViewPDFSelectedFirebaseState extends State<ViewPDFSelectedFirebase> {
   test() async{
   final urlSelected = 'CitationNeededBook-Sample.pdf';//url;
   print('urlSelected='+ urlSelected.toString());
   final file = await loadFirebase(urlSelected.toString());
   if (file==null) return;
   openPDF(this.context, file);
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { //this is generating a dark screen not needed. The view needed is on another page. But if I remove this build, I am getting an error.

    return Container(
    );
  }
  static Future<File> loadFirebase(String url) async {
    try {
      final refPDF = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(url);
      final bytes = await refPDF.getData();
      return _storeFile(url, bytes);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<File> _storeFile(String url, List<int> bytes) async {
    final filename = basename(url);
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    return file;
  }

   void openPDF(BuildContext context, File file) => Navigator.of(context).push(
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PDFViewerPage( file: file,)),);
}
```